# the meaning of the phrase 'the point of his lance scooped the eye of the circle'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Rafe says, the contests had not begun, he was running at the ring,
>   **the point of his lance scooped the eye of the circle**. Then the horse stumbled under him, man and rider down, horse rolling with a
>   scream and Henry beneath it.
>
> *Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel*

What is the meaning of the phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It' a dexterity/riding contest that dates back to medieval times:

A rider uses a lance and aims at a small ring suspended from a rope or on a stick. What was a relatively risk-free exercise for squires<sup>1</sup> is today still a local equestrian sport in Denmark, north-western Germany and the Netherlands.

I included a [newspaper article](http://www.selkirkweekendadvertiser.co.uk/news/local-news/tilting-towards-a-new-era-in-equine-sports-1-2421684), which gives a short overview of the modern sport and some additional pictures

---

<sup>1</sup> Boys training to become knights